# How to Pass Variable into Function

Tags: wordpress

I try to use SMTP to send email in Wordpress with the following code and it work.

```
function wow_phpmailer_init( $phpmailer ) {

$phpmailer->SMTPAuth = true;
$phpmailer->Host = 'mail.gmail.com';
$phpmailer->Port = '465';
$phpmailer->Username = 'my_email@gmail.com';
$phpmailer->Password = 'mypassword';
$phpmailer->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
$phpmailer->Mailer = 'smtp';

}
add_action( 'phpmailer_init', 'wow_phpmailer_init' );
```

Now what I need is to use dynamic value for each SMTP info, for example :

```
function wow_phpmailer_init( $phpmailer ) {

$phpmailer->SMTPAuth = true;
$phpmailer->Host = get_post_meta( $id, 'smtp_host', true );
$phpmailer->Port = get_post_meta( $id, 'smtp_port', true );
$phpmailer->Username = get_post_meta( $id, 'smtp_usr', true );
$phpmailer->Password = get_post_meta( $id, 'smtp_pass', true );
$phpmailer->SMTPSecure = get_post_meta( $id, 'smtp_encrypt', true );
$phpmailer->Mailer = 'smtp';

}
add_action( 'phpmailer_init', 'wow_phpmailer_init' );
```

The question is how to pass dynamic **$id** inside **function wow_phpmailer_init( $phpmailer )** without use **GLOBAL** var ( f*or example global $id;* ) etc ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is some missing context as I'm not sure where do_action('phpmailer_init') is happening. Most likely it's somewhere in your loop or in a place where a post id is being calculated. You can pass as many variables into the do_action as you need as long as you increase the parameter count on your add_action function.

```
<?php
// function signature
function wow_phpmailer_init( $phpmailer, $id ) {
    // do stuff
}
// argument count is the 4th parameter
add_action('phpmailer_init', 'wow_phpmailer_init', 10, 2);

// somewhere else in your code you have something like this
do_action('phpmailer_init', $phpmailer, $post_id);
```

**EDIT**: Another option is to use a Closure.

```
<?php
$id = ;// calculated id
add_action('phpmailer_init', function($phpmailer) use ($id) {
    // do stuff
});
wp_mail(); // send mail, which calls do_action('phpmailer_init')
```

Comment: Thank you @dgilmore,
phpmailer_init is default WP action hook, see here https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/phpmailer_init

When use your code we get Notice: Undefined variable: phpmailer error. Why?

Comment: I had assumed the hook was a custom one. I see now it's part of wp_mail. Are you just trying to get the current post id? Will the function get_the_ID(); work for you?

Comment: Hi, we already get the post ID but confuse how to add post ID into wow_phpmailer_init function.

Comment: So, your code is still out of context as I don't know when wp_mail is being called, when the id is being calculated and when the filter is being set. If you have control over these things a Closure may be your best bet. I've edited my answer.